# How do I force VPN user traffic to go through SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: ssh, iptables, vpn, firewall, proxy

I have a Raspberry Pi which establishes an SSH proxy to a remote server (VPS) and opens a port on the Pi so I can use it as a SOCKS proxy.  This is the command I use to establish the tunnel:

```
ssh -D 1080 -f -C -q -N user@hostname
```

This shows you how it is supposed to work:

```
                        ______________________________
                       |                              |
                       |            Client            |
                       |______________________________|
                                       |
                                       | L2TP over IPSEC
                       ________________|_______________ __ 
                      |                                |  |
                      |       VPN (192.168.1.XXX)      |  |
                      |________________________________|  |
                       ________________|_______________   |-RaspberryPi
                      |                                |  | 
                      |    SOCKS5 (127.0.0.1:1080)     |  |
                      |________________________________|__|
                                       |
                                       | SSH tunnel
                       ________________|________________
                      |                                 |
                      |         VPS (Amazon EC2)        |
                      |_________________________________|
                                       |
                                      / \
                                     /   \
                                  the internet
```

These are my IP tables:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 -o eth+ -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.43.0/24 -o eth+ -m policy --dir out --pol none -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol none -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 500,4500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -m policy --dir in --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1701 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -i eth+ -o ppp+ -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.42.0/24 -d 192.168.42.0/24 -i ppp+ -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.43.0/24 -i eth+ -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.43.0/24 -o eth+ -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
COMMIT
```

The script "[setup-ipsec-vpn](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn)" was used to make the VPN.

So my question is: How can I change these IP tables to drop all of the VPN clients' outbound packets unless it is using the SOCKS5 proxy on the Raspberry Pi (:1080)

Answer (score 1):

I just answered it there. basically you need to redirect all TCP to the socks client + add some tricks for DNS\udp.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/980819/create-a-vpn-connection-which-connects-to-a-socks-server/1423292#1423292

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/527620)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends in part on whether you will configure your clients.

In other words, do you intend for the SOCKS proxy to be explicit, or transparent?

If you can configure your client apps to use an explicit proxy, then it should be simple enough (although you may want to have your SOCKS listen on the VPN interface - or create a DNAT rule).

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.1.1 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

If you wanted to have a transparent proxy, I think it may be worth considering introducing haproxy.

This [haproxy blog post](https://blog.haproxy.com/2013/09/16/howto-transparent-proxying-and-binding-with-haproxy-and-aloha-load-balancer/) provides an overview of how to setup transparent binding, which sounds like it might work for your use case.

You may in that case find it easier to have SSH in tunnel mode rather than SOCKS (or add another VPN connection between Pi and gateway).

The specific rule causing your 'issue' right now is, I think, this one:

```
-A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth+ -j ACCEPT
```

More generally, it seems as though you might want to rewrite your firewall rules to achieve what you want.

Comment: The SOCKS proxy is explicit and defined in the VPN profiles for the clients. However, if the proxy is down, it ignores it and just uses the RaspberryPi's connection. I want to stop that from happening. If the proxy is down, their requests should not go anywhere

Answer (score 0):

As your diagram, your Rasperri Pi is both an L2TP server and an SSH proxy client. So the question lies on how to route all the outbound traffic into L2TP tunnel once established. It has nothing to do with your SSH proxy if you set it with `masquerade` option, meaning all the traffic from its clients would be masqueraded by the ip of Rasperri Pi itself, so that theSSH proxy server believes it is routing the traffic only for Rasperri Pi rather than for the original clients.